# Application installed from Test flight crashes in real device, while working fine in Simulator Xamarin.Forms iOS 13.6

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have recently update my OS to macOSCatalina 10.15.6 and Xcode to 11.6 version to support the latest Xamarin.iOS version 13.18.3.2 (Visual Studio Community).

I have implemented LinkedIn Login in my app, when I click on the LinkedIn login option it calls the iOS renderer I have created and runs the below code:

```
var rc = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator
(
    clientId: Keys.LinkedInClientId,
    clientSecret: Keys.LinkedInClientSecret,
    scope: "r_liteprofile r_emailaddress",
    authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization"),
    redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/company/coeqwety"),
    accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken"))
    {
        AllowCancel = true,
        ShowErrors = false,
        ClearCookiesBeforeLogin = true
    };

auth.Error += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    rc.DismissModalViewController(true);
};

auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    var token = eventArgs.IsAuthenticated;
    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userName = eventArgs.Account.Username;
    }
    else
    {
        // The user cancelled
    }
    rc.DismissModalViewController(true);
};

rc.PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, null);
```

Now when the rc.PresentViewController() gets called application get crash in real device while
same thing is working fine in simulator.

I have check the ApplicationOutput Window for details and in that I'm getting few lines which I think might be causing this issue, here it is:

> MyApp.iOS[9779:190200] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
>
> MyApp.iOS[9779:190200] CoreAnimation: [EAGLContext
> renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:] was called from a non-main thread
> in an implicit transaction! Note that this may be unsafe without an
> explicit CATransaction or a call to [CATransaction flush].
>
> MyApp.iOS[9779:190200] CoreAnimation: [EAGLContext
> renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:] was called from a non-main thread
> in an implicit transaction! Note that this may be unsafe without an
> explicit CATransaction or a call to [CATransaction flush].
>
> MyApp.iOS[9779:190200] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

After this I have done R&D using this messages and then I have Wrapped my code inside various method like:

- InvokeOnMainThread()
- Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()
- DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync()

For Example:

```
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        rc.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
        rc.PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, null);
    });
});
```

But none of this things worked and app is still crashing, any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

> **Updates: getting this exception as I have added --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal in additional mtouch argument with linker behavior
> Link from sdk only**

```
{System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IOS' threw an exception. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Linked Away
  at UIKit.DeprecatedWebView..ctor (CoreGraphics.CGRect ) [0x00000] in 
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.3.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIWebView.g.cs:99 
  at Xamarin.Auth.WebViewConfiguration+IOS.UserAgentFromUIWebView () [0x00000] in <85539ee049364f3e8d64880a4a42b589>:0 
  at Xamarin.Auth.WebViewConfiguration+IOS..cctor () [0x00041] in <85539ee049364f3e8d64880a4a42b589>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Xamarin.Auth.WebAuthenticatorController..ctor (Xamarin.Auth.WebAuthenticator authenticator) [0x00000] in <85539ee049364f3e8d64880a4a42b589>:0 
  at Xamarin.Auth.WebAuthenticator.GetPlatformUIEmbeddedBrowser () [0x00002] in <85539ee049364f3e8d64880a4a42b589>:0 
  at Xamarin.Auth.WebAuthenticator.GetPlatformUI () [0x000c3] in <85539ee049364f3e8d64880a4a42b589>:0 
  at Xamarin.Auth.Authenticator.GetUI () [0x00000] in <85539ee049364f3e8d64880a4a42b589>:0 
  at MyApp.iOS.RendererClasses.AuthenticationButtonRenderer.LinkedIn_call   }
```

> Line where exception occur: rc.PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(),
> true, null);

This is the page (Left image) I have discussed above, when In icon clicked it open this web page (right side image)

[image]

Comment: what is the exception causing the crash?

Comment: That is what I'm not getting as catch block not get called. I'm getting this message in xcode's crash section: xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread